¿Por que mi script no se ejecuta en un proyecto de angular?
Hola soy nueva empezando a trabajar con Angular 17, tengo problemas con los script creados dentro de la pagina html. tengo un proyecto donde tengo que cambiar el color del menu al hacer scroll pero al ejecutar el proyecto veo que el script no los ejecuta.
mi codigo index :
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>      
      <script>
    const navEl = document.querySelector('.navbar');

      window.addEventListener ('scroll' , () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 56) {
          navEl.classList.add('navbar-scrolled');
        } else if (window.scrollY <= 56) {
          navEl.classList.remove('navbar-scrolled');
        }
      });
 </script>
    </body>
    </html>

Mi codigo del menu:

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="assets/images/logo_sol_v1.png" width="310" height="auto" class="d-inline-block align-top img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center"                 id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" [routerLink]="['/home']" >Inicio </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Servicios
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
    
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Experiencia Laboral
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Proyectos relevantes</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Certificaciones</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Galería</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Distribuidores</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mesa de ayuda</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

CSS
  /*google font*/
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700,800,900&display=swap');
    *{
      font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
     }
    .bg {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.459);
    }
    
    .nav-link{
      color:white;
      font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
      color:#dc3545;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
      color:#dc3545 !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav .nav-link.show{
      color:#dc3545 !important;
    }
    
    .navar{
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .navbar-scrolled{
      background-color:#17273b;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

El Script lo que hace es que al hacer el scroll va agregar la clase al nav con el nuevo color pero no lo hace, y me di cuenta por que igual estaba trabajando una librería que tenia que escribir el codigo script para que se ejecutara y tampoco lo hace.
No se si se puede hacer de otra forma o donde tengo que colocar el script para que funcione.

Intentaste hacerlo todo en el AppComponent? Usualmente en Angular se hace diferente, tienes que declarar que es del tipo HTMLElement o algo así. Lo otro que puedes hacer es crear un servicio para por ejemplo activar el modo oscuro. En el index.html no se suele hacer nada.

Lo tengo por secciones, ejemplo tengo un componente para el menú, otro para el contenido. investigare como se hace un servicio, muchas gracias por las ideas. Saludos

@René "tienes que declarar que es del tipo HTMLElement o algo así" -> No confundas ANGULAR con TYPESCRIPT. En Angular ejecutar JS puro es una opción válida (si bien no la más recomendada, pero vamos, que no tiene ningún problema). Otra cosa es que estés usando TYPESCRIPT para trabajar y lo CORRECTO sea declarar los tipos. Y digo lo correcto, porque realmente no es necesario tampoco. Incluso usando typescript puedes ignorar los tipos, a no ser que uses el modo estricto, entonces te obliga a declararlos, pero es puramente indicaciones en tiempo de compilación y tu código JS funciona igual.

Entonces alguna sugerencia?

investigando encontré la solución aquí les proporciono el link del video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yO-_SE5gUfQ
Les agradezco a las personas que se tomaron el tiempo para ayudarme.
Saludos

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
